# Steps to clean a string works individually, but not in a function

Tags: r, function

This is driving me crazy. I have written a function to clean strings.
When I try each and every step individually, it works. But when called all together in a function, it fails.
Can you spot what's wrong?
Also, I'm sure there are ways to make this more efficient, but this is beyond my limited capabilities.

Here's the code for the various steps:

```
x <- "le touquet - paris plage"
x
```

I first remove accents etc.

```
x <- stri_trans_general(x, "upper; latin-ascii")
x
```

Second I remove hyphens etc and replace some words by their abbreviations

```
x <- stri_replace_all_regex(x, c("-", "[.]", "[/]", "[']", "\\bSAINT\\b", "\\bSAINTE\\b", "  "), c(" ", " ", " SUR ", " ", "ST", "STE", " "), case_insensitive = TRUE, vectorize=F)
x
```

This creates extra whitespace which I want to remove in the next step:

```
x <- gsub("\\s+", " ", x)
x
```

And for good measure, I make sure there are no leading or trailing spaces:

```
x <- trimws(x)
x
```

This works fine and the end result is "LE TOUQUET PARIS PLAGE"

But when I put all this in the function below, I end up with a double space between TOUQUET and PARIS:

```
preprocess_string <- function(x) {
  x <- stri_trans_general(x, "upper; latin-ascii") # to remove accents etc.
  x <- stri_replace_all_regex(x, c("-", "[.]", "[/]", "[']", "\\bSAINT\\b", "\\bSAINTE\\b", "  "), c(" ", " ", " SUR ", " ", "ST", "STE", " "), case_insensitive = TRUE, vectorize=F)
  x <- gsub("\\s+", " ", x)
  x <- trimws(x)
  return(x)
}
x
```

I have spent a few hours trying to understand why is this happening but to no avail.

Also, I'm using it to create a new column (using mutate and sapply), and it takes ages to run (over 5 minutes for a dataframe with 700k rows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers,
Bernard

Comment: Are you actually calling the function?
`preprocess_string(x)`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, for me `preprocess_string(x)` returns `"LE TOUQUET PARIS PLAGE"`. I'm on win11, R-4.2.3, english locale.

Comment: Sorry, yes I am calling the function as follows: preprocess_string("le touquet - paris plage"), and it returns "LE TOUQUET  PARIS PLAGE" with two spaces between TOUQUET and PARIS.. I'm on macOS 13.2.1, R-4.2.2, and it says "Natural language support but running in an English locale"

Comment: I cant reproduce this error either when running `preprocess_string("le touquet - paris plage")` - it returns `"LE TOUQUET PARIS PLAGE"`. I'm on a Mac v13.3.1 with R v4.2.2. Try restarting R?

Comment: Oh goodness, now it's working! Restarting R did it, thank you. I suppose a previous version of my function got stuck in memory? Still very slow, but at least it's working. Thanks!